# Can Kalman filter reduce node density in a sensor network?

Tags: matlab, filter, sensors, kalman-filter

I studied that Kalman filter can suppress noise present in an indoor environment and can be used to predict the future position of a target. But i want to know whether with the help of Kalman filter, can we make the localization error minimum with less number of nodes?

For example :

I have a sensor network with 10 nodes initially. Without kalman filter, i get some localization error (say 5) from the estimated position and original position of target.

Then i increase the node density to 20 and get the localization error again.. this time its (say 2)

Now i want to know if i use kalman filter, is it possible to get localization error (3 or 4) which is nearer to sensor network with 20 nodes?

please help me on this.

regards,
Rias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always reach better noise levels with a filter, hence you will need less sensors. The issue is your system is nonlinear (in the most ideal case, your sensor output will depend on the inverse of euclidean distance of the target) In that case there are nonlinear extensions to Kalman filter like EKF and UKF, although I would suggest [particle filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter) which is the most general sequential filter that uses Monte Carlo techniques. Here is a wikipedia article that discusses [radar tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_tracker), which I guess is similar to your problem. Moreover, check the extended kalman filter lecture [here](http://soliton.ae.gatech.edu/people/eferon/AE6531/), there is a nice example in the lecture which is pretty similar to your case.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. What parameter i must increase in kalman filter, to set a threshold for estimation which will reduce the noise to greater extent.

Should i need to increase the Kalman gain or Noise Covariance matrix for this purpose?

Comment: Noise Covariance matrix can be modified in your case.